# How to disable and enable all the buttons with same class present on form on AJAX function call in following scenario?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, disabled-control, ajax-request

I've multiple buttons with same class called "normalbtn". If user clicks on any one of these button AJAX function is called. I want to disable all the other buttons having class "normalbtn" disbaled while the AJAX request processes.

When the success response comes from the request all the buttons with class "normalbtn" should get enabled.

How should I achieve this by making necessary change in following function code?

```
function change_value(data_url, op, id, value) { 
  var data_value = value;

  $.post(data_url, {'op':op, 'id':id, 'value':data_status }, function(data) {
    if(data_value=='0') { 
      var value = '1'; 
      $('#data_value_'+id+' button').text("On");


    } else {  
      var value = '0';
      $('#data_value_'+id+' button').text("Off");

    }
    $('#data_value_'+id).attr('onClick', "change_value('"+data_url+"', '"+op+"', '"+id+"', '"+value+"');return false;");          
  });   
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you try $('.normalbtn').prop('disabled', true). Could you post your HTML too. attr('onClick') is a discouraged way.

Comment: @cforcloud:I know this but where should I write this in my code? And also the code to enable these buttons once success response comes should also be added. But where?

Answer (score 0):

Disable it before the post and enable back on success.

```
$('.normalbtn').prop('disabled', true);

$.post(data_url, {'op':op, 'id':id, 'value':data_status }, function(data) {
   /// on success
   $('.normalbtn').prop('disabled', false);
});
```

EDIT:
instead of attr('onClick') way, try using the 'data' attribute http://api.jquery.com/data/